# QGIS 3 how to customize line dash symbology

Tags: symbology, line, qgis-3, style, specification

I want to keep the same line width but specify a much longer dash.

The symbology controls in QGIS 3 have changed significantly from 2.X, so the many answers re: line symbology control for QGIS 2.X are now obsolete.

When I attempt to edit the settings using the button-dropdown to the right of the `Stroke style` field, I invoke an `Expression String Builder` that might enable me to customize stroke styles to my heart's delight; but the syntax is not explained.

It looks like it expecting an SQL expression, because it looks like a similar dialog box for managing Attributes. But I cannot find any documentation on how it works. The "Expected Format: string [no|solid|dash|dot|dash dot|dash dot dot]" is cryptic.

Comment: The "Expected Format: string [no|solid|dash|dot|dash dot|dash dot dot]" refer to selecting between the predefined pattern (the same you can set in the drop list : Stroke Style). To create your own pattern see JGH answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Ah! @JGH gave the vital clue. I thought that controlling line-stroke for polylines and the edges of polygons would have the same controls. I am editing symbology for polygon edges. By default on my QGIS 3 install (Linux) no options are presented:

[image: QGIS 3 Symbology Dialog for Polygon Layer]

When I open the Symbol Layer Type drop-down field, I can select control of the Outline:

[image: QGIS 3 Symbology Dialog: Symbol Layer Type subfield]

And then I have access to the controls which @JGH describes! Yay!

[image: QGIS 3 Symbology Dialog with Line-Stroke control enabled]

This may indeed be the same as in QGIS 2.18. I must not have tried to customize the line-stroke of a polygon-edge while using 2.18. While searching this issue, I did not encounter instructions which advised that polygon-edge symbology control is different, and that one must select for Outline:Simple line in order to add controls to the dialog box. I hope this helps others with the keywords I have laid out.

BTW I tried to add this as a comment to @JGH's answer, but [CTRL]+[G] did not add images to a comment; so I created this as an answer to my own question. But @JGH gets credit for the vital hint.

Comment: I can't see any technical reason why this is not implemented for simple fill outlines... :-(

Answer (score 2):

The `Stroke style` allows you to select a predefined style.

To create a new dash pattern, tick the check box `use custom dash pattern` then click the `change` button.

From there, declare the dash length then the blank length. If you define several patterns, they are rendered one after another.

In the example below, the pattern is: black line for 15 mm, blank for 2 mm, black line for 1 mm, blank for 2 mm; and repeat the pattern.

[image]

PS: it is the same in QGIS 3 or 2.18